# Orthographic Cam with HDRI in background

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine, hdri, orthographic

Basically I'm trying to make an animation birthday card 4 my friend. There is this airbus a400m plane scene, which I'm trying to film it like mission impossible fallout. The view of the plane is in orthographic, and the problem is that with using orthographic cam on blender, I can't see MY HDRI. Increasing the distance didn't quite work so pls give me some tips thx.

Answer (score 2):

The longer the camera lens, the smaller part of HDRI is visible.
Orthographic camera is infinitely long, so it only shows one pixel of your HDRI.

> Solution: Use a perspective camera.

[image]